# Positioning Inline-Block "Triangle" after Navigation Link

Tags: css, position, geometry, inline

So I am trying to get this to working somthing like a List Bullet, but at the END of the Navigation Button.

I am having PROBLEMS WITH the Black Triangle positioning itself too far up. It raises higher than the text I have (w/ black BG).

Below is an example of my issue.

http://dabblet.com/gist/3483670

I have tried alot of different things, but I am completely stumped.
Probably something silly I am overlooking, but it might need a serious of work arounds I am not aware of.

Thanks for all the help.

Incase the Link does not work for you. See Below.

CSS

```
 a {font: 19px/26px 'Exo',Arial,sans-serif;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
    padding: 0 0 58px;
    font-weight:100;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration:none;}

    a[rel="catagory"] { background:#000000; padding:0 5px 0 5px; color:#BAFF32;}

.triangle { width: 0;
    height: 0; 
    background:no-repeat right center;
    border-top: 0px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left: 15px solid black;
    display:inline-block;}
```

HTML

```
<a href="index.html" rel="catagory"><span class="plus">+</span> <span>HOME</span></a><span class="triangle"></span>
```

Comment: it Looks like it raises my Line-Height. I'm Stumped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add

```
a[rel="catagory"] {
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
    width:auto;
    line-height:25px;
}
.triangle {
    vertical-align:middle
}
```

**Explanation:**

The part which aligns them is

```
a[rel="catagory"] {vertical-align:middle;}
.triangle {vertical-align:middle}
```

But anchor's height is 22px, so we need

```
a[rel="catagory"] {
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:25px;
}
```

in order to make the height 25px.

But you have another rule (I wonder why):

```
a{width:100%}
```

Before setting `display:inline-block` the anchor has `display:inline`, so that rule does nothing.

But now it works and we want to disable it, so we need

```
a[rel="catagory"] {
    width:auto;
}
```